# How I can get more than 1 array?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am creating a game where in the client I am supposed to get some arrays from a server and reveal them into the screen. I can press the button X times to get X arrays.

Currently I am using this code

```
 rollDiceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            rollDice();

            try {
                int[] tempArray = new GetDiceTask().execute(socket).get();
                printDice(tempArray,pDice);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

but if I don't like this array and I want another one I cannot use the AsyncTask cause I get the common error for `Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once)`.

This is my code for AsyncTask.

```
@Override
protected int[] doInBackground(Socket...params) {
    Socket soc = params[0];

    try {
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
        int[] tempArray = (int[]) (ois.readObject());
        return tempArray;
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Is there a way that I can take multiple arrays without that exception?

Comment: You need to create a new instance of Asynctask and then call execute.
There is no  need to call `get()` as it blocks the ui thread waiting for the result.

Comment: @Raghunandan so I need an array for each instant, right? Should I use a List of arrays of integers?